# Refactoring of a custom case of validation

Tags: c#, validation, design-patterns

I have a hierarchy of classes for validation and i'm at a point that i'd like to refactor (if possible and useful) leaving the code decoupled.

```
    public class DefaultValidation : ValidationList
    {
       public DefaultValidation(Cutomer customer, Dto dto)
       {
        DefaultRepository repository = new DefaultRepository();

        EntityBook entityBook = (EntityBook)repository.GetBookById(dto.IdBook);
        this.Add(new BookMustBeValidValidation(entityBook));

        EntityVideo entityVideo = (EntityVideo)repository.GetVideoById(dto.IdVideo);
        this.Add(new VideoValidation(entityTask));
        this.Add(new OtherNecessaryValidation(dto.OtherProperty));
       }
    }
```

This class is a concrete for validation. I add all the rules in a list so i can add various kind of validation in form of classes.

(I used this [method](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2014/01/05/SOLID-validation-class-with-easy-logical-implication.aspx) that seemed interesting)

The need of a refactory comes when i add another similar class:

```
    public class SpecialValidation : ValidationList
    {
     public SpecialValidation(Cliente cliente, DtoRichiesta richiesta)
     {
        this.Add(new OtherNecessaryValidation(dto.OtherProperty));
        this.Add(new SpecialAnotherOneValidation(dto.AnotherProperty));
     }
    }
```

The root is in common, the difference is what classes (rules) i inject to the list.
Do you think something should be changed?
Thanks

Comment: Interesting approach. However, one thing I don't like is the use of exceptions. Exceptions have 2 disadvantages: 1) They are a performance drain 2) When one exception is thrown, it prevents you from viewing the rest of the invalid assertions. There is a similar business rule engine in the [CSLA framework](https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/blob/d3a2b0707f56b619d6ad46a517a572f3fdeb729d/Samples/ProjectTracker/ProjectTracker.BusinessLibrary.Shared/ValidRole.cs) that allows you to view all of the issues so you don't have to keep correcting and submitting them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the need for different validation classes

```
DefaultValidation vs SpecialValidation
```

Why don't you have a general validation class with a list of lets say `IValidables` that is filled according to your needs. So for each different list it's like you have a total different validation class... does it makes sense?

Comment: I made it simple, the reason is that every validation implements an interface so i can use a Factory Pattern to instantiate the correct class. Imagine customers with different rules. I instantiate the proper class and attach the rules. The client has to know nothing, but only its ID. In other words the flow is: Client passes the ID of a customer, a Factory returns the proper validation class and a simple call on "IsValid" gives me the result. I hope is clearer, now.